# How can I integrate a checkout link for my Watson whatsapp Chatbot

Tags: twilio, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I'm currently building a chatbot for a restaurant, to take orders and attend to customers queries,  I have done all the ground work, the only issue is the payment integration, please how can I integrate a payment gateway to the bot to allow customers to checkout easily. Thanks

Is there any api or webhook to use in other to allow payment in my chatbot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IBM watson custom extensions](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson-assistant?topic=watson-assistant-build-custom-extension)